# How to split a single column into multiple columns in SQL Server select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am new to SQL Server . I have a single long column with names starting from a, b, c and d. I want to show them in separate columns of NameA, NameB, NameC and NameD. I tried union but it shows in one column. I tried case but I dont know how to use it. Please help.

Existing column

```
names
A1
B1
A2
C1
A3
A4

A_names| B_names | C_names
A1     | B1      | C1
A2
A3
A4
```

Comment: Instead of a UNION, you'd use a CASE expression for each column.

Comment: That's an odd requirement. How do you know which NameA's to match with which NameB's? Or doesn't it matter? Are you sure you want this? And why? Also: please give some sample data with desired results.

Comment: Is the data in the NAME column delimited?

Comment: @popovitsj All I want is to write a select statement which answers names starting with a in one column and names starting with b in another column and so on

Comment: Please add some sample data, i.e. your users table data and your desired output.  It's very likely you're asking for something other than what you actually want here - adding the sample will help clarify for yourself and others.

Comment: It's really hard to think of a usecase for this. What you're asking is a representational thing, which you should really solve in your application, not in your sql query.

Comment: @popovitsj Yeah this is a good clue. I think I should take this column as a dataset SSRS and then put it in multiple columns and then filter them.

Answer (score 4):

just for fun and curious why you want that:

```
select * 
from 
( select idx = left(names,1)
       , names
       , rn = row_number() over (partition by left(names,1) order by names) 
  from 
  ( values ('A1'),('B1'),('A2'),('C1'),('A3'),('A4'),('B2')) 
  v(names)
) dat
pivot 
( max(names)
  for idx in ([A],[B],[C],[D])
) p
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4013/0

Comment: Actually, I thought after splitting names column in multiple columns, I will import it as dataset in SSRS and then assign each column to a column in table to show in a report.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is something that should be solved in SQL. It's a representational thing that should probably be done in the application.

However, if you insist to use SQL for this, this is how you could do it. The main problem with this query is that the ROW_NUMBER function will be quite bad for performance.

```
WITH nameA
(
   SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) AS rn
   FROM t1
   WHERE name LIKE 'a%'
), nameB AS
(
   SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) AS rn
   FROM t1
   WHERE name LIKE 'b%'
)
SELECT name FROM nameA
FULL OUTER JOIN nameB
ON nameA.rn = nameB.rn
ORDER BY nameA.rn,nameB.rn;
```

Comment: This will work, but it's going to make the database engine jump through a lot of expensive hoops that would be cheaper in the presentation layer (which I think the answerer knows)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CASE (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

This Query should work:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN users.name like 'a%' THEN users.name  ELSE NULL END AS NameA,
    CASE WHEN users.name like 'b%' THEN users.name  ELSE NULL END AS NameB,
    CASE WHEN users.name like 'c%' THEN users.name  ELSE NULL END AS NameC,
    CASE WHEN users.name like 'd%' THEN users.name  ELSE NULL END AS NameD
FROM users
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear that this satisfies the original question.  It would produce output where you have a row for each name with lots of nulls.

Comment: no it won't. This will give rows like `null, null, claire, null`

Comment: You both are right. It gave a similar output but contains a lot of null

Comment: I think I cant display it without null. Can I get a count of them in seperate columns because I want to make a report of bar chart with their column names

Comment: Of course it's possible, to get the result that you want, it's just not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post, it is very close to your problem. 
[Itzik Ben-Gan  |  SQL Server Pro](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/splitting-data-one-column-three-columns)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the way relational databases work.  When you have data in the same row, it's supposed to be related in some way - a common ID, at the least.  What is it that would connect the person whose name happens to begin with A to the person whose name happens to begin with B?  Why would you ever want the RDBMS to make such an arbitrary connection?

If you have a requirement to display users in such a way, you'd just want to write several queries and have your presentation layer deal with laying them out properly, e.g.

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'a%'
SELECT name FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'b%'
SELECT name FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'c%'
etc...
```

The presentation layer could run each query and then populate a table appropriately.  Even better would be to have the presentation layer just run this query:

```
SELECT name FROM users
```

And then appropriately sort and display the data, which is probably going to be less expensive than multiple scans on your users table by SQL Server.